# Why can't the LED flash for a while?

Tags: capacitor

I am new to electronic circuits. I made a circuit as this picture shows:

[image]

I want the LED to flash for a while when the switch is open, but it seems the capacitor doesn't do its job well.

- power source input: 5 V
- both resistors: 100 ohms each
- capacitor :100 μF, 50 V

Comment: you probably want the cap parallel with the LED or LED+resistor. Add some graphs, like the cap and LED to get a better understanding of the open/close circuit changes.

Comment: Can you describe for us how you believe that this circuit would make the LED flash rather than just being turned on?

Comment: @brhans I think OP is using "flash" to mean "lit" - translation error.

Comment: @brhans I guess he means *temporarily lit* (as opposed to *periodically flashing*).

Comment: If you want to light an LED, maybe it helps to add an LED to the circuit?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The capacitor and resistors will have a time constant given by τ = RC = 100 × 10<sup>-6</sup> × 200 = 2 × 10<sup>-2</sup> s = 0.02 s.

The delay is there. You just can't see it.

Comment: Thank you. you are quite right. My origin T=100ohms x 100uF=0.1sec. so I changed a new resistor with 10kohms. Now I can see the LED delays when I turn off the switch!

Answer (score 15):

Let's start out simple. You have a 5V power source (represented by the battery symbol in your schematic), a current-limiting 100 Ω resistor, and the LED.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fV7gAK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Let's re-arrange this a bit to follow a convention, just to make it more "readable" to other engineers. Typically we place ground (negative) toward the bottom, and have the signal or current generally flow from left to right:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fr6e1h.png)</sup>

Next, you mention a switch, but there's not a switch shown in your schematic. I presume you mean when you disconnect or turn off the power supply.

My guess is that you want to be able to turn off power and keep the LED lit for a brief time by using a capacitor.

Based on your schematic, you've connected the capacitor and another 100 Ω resistor in parallel. Drawn more conventionally, you have:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fz94O3.png)</sup>

When the power is connected, current will flow through both R1 and the LED, but also R2 and C1 because they are in parallel. Once C1 is charged, no more current will flow through that branch because capacitors block DC. But that's OK, you just want it to stay charged so that when you disconnect power, it will provide power to the LED.

Now think about what happens when the power is removed or disconnected:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkPLmL.png)</sup>

Charge in the capacitor will cause a current to flow from its positive side to its negative side*. Since it cannot flow through the open where the power source used to be, it will necessarily have to flow through R2, then R1, then the LED, and finally back to the negative terminal.

If R1 is limiting current through the LED, then you can hopefully see how R2 is unnecessary. In theory you might have R2 to limit current while charging C1, but unlikely. When power is disconnected then, you have 200 Ω of resistance between the capacitor and LED.

Finally, and I think this may be the point of your question, you may be expecting the 100µF capacitor to keep the LED going for a few seconds or something, but it doesn't appear to be doing that. The reason is because 100µF is actually not that much capacitance when you are talking about driving an LED.

Also remember that when a capacitor discharges, its voltage drops from the charge voltage to zero in about [5 "time constants"](https://electronicsreference.com/calculators/capacitor_charge_calculator/) where a time constant is the resistance times the capacitance. 100µF \$\times\$ 200 Ω = 0.02 seconds. 0.02 seconds \$\times\$ 5 = 0.1 second (100 milliseconds). But remember your LED also has a forward voltage (probably around 2 volts), so it doesn't even get to stay on that long, because as soon as the capacitor drops below 2 volts, the LED cannot light.

If you just want to experiment, try a much larger capacitor: 4700µF would be about 4.7 seconds, minus some time because the LED won't work below ~2 volts.

Hopefully this helps you both see how to draw the schematic as well as the relationship between capacitor size and the time the LED stays lit when you disconnect power.

<sub>** In conventional current flow.*</sub>

Comment: Using a 1F supercap this is a simple way to implement a standlight on dynamo bike lighting.  Then you typically do want the additional resistance  as the standlight (at least at the front) is normally dimmer than the running light.  There are of course better ways that use the full capacitance more.